# PHP + ie6 + cookies: failing a hello world world for cookies

Tags: php, cookies, internet-explorer-6, setcookie

I tried, to no avail! **My problem is php's setcookie() fails in IE6.** It's fully functioning (albeit buggy) for Firefox 3 and IE7/8. The following is the code.  IE6 displays fail. Simple question: why?

```
<?
    header('P3P: CP="DEV PSAi NAV STP DEM OTRo NOI IDC 
                     DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"'); 

    setcookie('hello', 'poopoo');

    echo $_COOKIE['hello'];
?>
```

**I suspected P3P** ([link](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/p3p-cookies-ie6/2/)), **or maybe some bug with the timezone**-- IE6 javascript not converting time to the same standard that php uses (so that all server-issued cookies are automatically expired).

Here's what I've done:
For the p3p issue, I inserted the above header tag.  I've also created a policy file, and a policy reference, and run the my site through w3c's p3p checker with no errors.

For the timezone issues, I reset the time zone in browscap.ini. I also tweaked my clock forward, and backward by 24 hours.

If you can give me any new things to try, it would be very much appreciated.  All I need is a Hello World cookie setter for IE6.

I appreciate it.

*Update: **I caught wind that the standalone IE6 has issues that match this. Can anyone with IE6 do a quick check that you can add items to the cart on my [alpha](http://mgxvideo.com/mgxcopy-alpha)?**

Comment: Am I missing something? You set a cookie named 'groos' and tried to print a cookie named 'hello'... what did you expect?

Comment: @Paolo, embarrassing mistake from trying to combine two files and post without testing. Thx.

Comment: I suggest you post your answer as an actual answer instead of inside your question and marking the title with "[solved]". You can accept it after two days. That way it won't appear in the unanswered list forever.

Comment: Accept the answer, I mean. I.e. give it one of those green checkmarks. You can only do that after 48 hours on your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final Update: Bug caused by standalone ie6 run on vista. Dl'ed official msft virtual pc and virtual hd and the site worked perfect.**

Answer (score 0):

What are the security settings for IE?

Could it be that the security settings on it don't allow you to write cookies for it?

Comment: Dude, I set it at pants-down setting. I'm naked for the world to feed me cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The $_COOKIE array is filled during your script initialisation. It is not changed by setcookie : the value will have changed at next page loading.

See the php manual for the [setcookie](http://us.php.net/setcookie) function :

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the **next** page load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.